# Python 2.7 Not plotting extremes based on slope in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Basically, I want to not plot extremes in my graph. I thought doing this based on the slope of the graph would be a good idea, but for some reason I keep getting the error that the dates on my x-axis do not exist (DataFrame has no attribute Datumtijd). (Edit: Removed file location as question has been answered)

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as pld
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
pbn135 = pd.read_csv('3873_135.csv', parse_dates=[0], index_col = 0, dayfirst = True, delimiter = ';', usecols = ['Datumtijd','DisplayWaarde'])
pbn135.plot()

for i in range(len(pbn135)):
    slope = (pbn135.DisplayWaarde[i+1]-pbn135.DisplayWaarde[i])/(pbn135.Datumtijd[i+1]-pbn135.Datumtijd[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python can't operate with DateTime. Converting the DateTime to an integer works. Usually done by calculating the total seconds from a reference date (e.g. 1 jan 2015).

This is done by importing `datetime` from `datetime`. Then by setting a reference date `datetime(2015,1,1)` the seconds are calculted with `total_seconds()`.

However this does create a slope where the interval is in seconds and not the interval of your datetime. If anyone knows how to fix that without manually entering a division please let us know

```
from datetime import datetime

for i in range(len(pbn135)):
    slope = (pbn135.pbn73[i+1]-pbn135.pbn73[i])/((pbn135.index[i+1]-datetime(2015,1,1)).total_seconds()-(pbn135.index[i]-datetime(2015,1,1)).total_seconds())
    print slope
```